# Broadcom BC4313

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I have the Broadcom BC4313 wirless chipset. I can't get it to work... I tried almost any guide I could find online...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1617380
this one looked promising, but I don't have the brcm80211 folder, did the workaround found there, with the ~/linux-next-a694cb1
but when i try to make the file, i get an error..

A few months ago, I had the same problem and I managed to get it working somehow..
If you need more info, or posting some output or something, let me know.
Any help would be appreciated..
Carmel
EDIT:
the lspci -v output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d0605000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d060a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at d0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d0500000-d05fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0400000-00000000d04fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at d0609000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Memory at d0608000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at d0604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 051b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-da-ff-ff-2b-c0-f8
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel modules: bcma, brcmsmac

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3975
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 13-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default drivers that Ubuntu uses for your Broadcom Wireless card does not work. To get the card working again, try the following:

1) Click Settings > Additional Drivers, then remove the driver, if any, for your WiFi card.

2) Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` to bring up your Terminal

3) Then type the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
$ sudo reboot
```

4) After you reboot your computer and log in, your WiFi should work again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. it didn't work. now I don't even have the "Enable Wireless" (which did nothing when clicked). it doesn't show that in the menu..
Something should be blacklisted in the blacklist.conf?

Comment: Did you do the steps listed here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1617380 ?  If so, you will have to undo those changes. Also ensure that you have the WiFi button switched to on on the computer itself.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't get pass the the make file.. so I don't know what to change back...

Comment: Did you just installed Ubuntu on a computer? If so, it would not hurt to reinstall Ubuntu and use the steps above to install the drivers for your WiFi.

Comment: I didn't do any steps... I would prefer very much not to install in all again... maybe upgrading to 12.04 would help?

Comment: Upgrading to 12.04 will not help. Getting the Broadcom WiFi cards working in Ubuntu takes patience. Try this, type the following command in Terminal and post the output here, `$ sudo lspci -v`.

Comment: edited my question with the output

Comment: Try the solution in the following link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: Thanks! that one worked, after marking for reinstalling in Synaptic! WiFi now works! Thanks alot

Comment: It stopped working after restart... redoing it doesn't work... any suggestions?